# Initialize automtatically selectInput in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

So I have this selectInput where I ask the user which variables does he want to keep from the dataframe. The problem is I want that a specific variable is always pre-selected or at least added to the select list after he made his choice.

For example I ask which variables does he want to keep from : "Color","Length","Name","Price","Website"

Let's say he chose "Name" and "Price" but I always want that the variable "Website" is in the select, how can I add it to the list after his choice ?

And if he choose "Name" and "Website" so he took the variable I really need, how do I do so the program doesn't add "Website" twice!

Thanks in advance, a fellow r user who just discovered today rShiny !

Have a good day

**EDIT : Alright I'm dumb, I tried the option selected, it didn't work but it's because I put it at the wrong selectInput**

**So yeah, this is just by using the option selected, sorry**